# Filtering an Audio Signal

Tags: matlab, filter

I made Equiripple FIR high pass filter using FDAtool in MATLAB. I want to pass a voice signal from this filter and select only high frequency part of the voice input. The problem is I don't know how to pass the voice input through this filter.

Any ideas how can I do it?

Comment: Where is the actual problem? Reading the audio signal or filtering it?

Comment: Reading the audio signal

Comment: In that case that should be the title of your question. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wavread('filename') converts a wav file into number array.
Try searching "Audio Processing with MatLab" for details.

Answer (score 0):

Read the voice signal from a file into a vector, then use something like

```
d = fdesign.highpass('N,Fc',10,1000,48000);
hp = design(d);
signal = filter(hp, signal)
```

found here:

http://www.mathworks.de/de/help/dsp/ref/fdesign.highpass.html